# SharePoint 2013 people picker for publishing contact

Tags: sharepoint, autocomplete, peoplepicker

I've created my custom page layout with custom content type (but derived from the content type page) on SharePoint 2013 in a publishing website. I have several field controls placed on the page layout (Title, some custom taxonomy fields, etc.) so I can change them directly in edit mode of the page. That works perfectly fine.

But there is the field "PublishingContact" (standard people field which comes with the content type of the article page) which can be set on the editform.aspx with the autocompletion control. I lost in placing this control on the page layout like i did with the others.

I've tried the classic "UserField" control, but this has no autocompletion. I've tried the ClientPeoplePicker but this control has no Property to map it to the corresponding field.

So has anyone an idea how to place the control of the editform on my page layout so I have the same functionality as on the editform, but on my page layout?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as i know, i had always use UserField Control. It doesn't provide auto completion but give you the verification button and the browse button.